# How to merge array index values and create a hash

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to convert an array into a hash by using some matching. Before converting the array into a hash, I want to merge the values like this

```
 "Desc,X1XXSC,C,CCCC4524,xxxs,xswd"
```

and create a hash from it. The rule is that, first value of the array is the key in Hash, in array there are repeating keys, for those keys I need to merge values and place it under one key.  "Desc:" are keys. My program looks like this.

```
 p 'test sample application'
 str = "Desc:X1:C:CCCC:Desc:XXSC:xxxs:xswd:C:4524"
 arr = Array.new
 arr = str.split(":")
 p arr
 test_hash = Hash[*arr]
 p test_hash
```

I could not find a way to figure it out. If any one can guide me, It will be thankful.

Comment: Describe the rules for merging the values

Comment: Sure hold on i will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small variation on @Sergio Tulentsev's solution:

```
str = "Desc:X1:C:CCCC:Desc:XXSC:xxxs:xswd:C:4524"
str.split(':').each_slice(2).each_with_object(Hash.new{""}){|(k,v),h| h[k] += v}
# => {"Desc"=>"X1XXSC", "C"=>"CCCC4524", "xxxs"=>"xswd"}
```

- `str.split(':')` results in an array; there is no need for initializing with `arr = Array.new`
- `each_slice(2)` feeds the elements of this array two by two to a block or to the method following it, like in this case.
- `each_with_object` takes those two elements (as an array) and passes them on to a block, together with an object, specified by:
- `(Hash.new{""})` This object is an empty Hash with special behaviour: when a key is *not* found then it will respond with a value of "" (instead of the usual nil).
- `{|(k,v),h| h[k] += v}` This is the block of code which does all the work. It takes the array with the two elements and deconstructs it into two strings, assigned to k and v; the special hash is assigned to h. h[k] asks the hash for the value of key "Desc". It responds with "", to which "X1" is added. This is repeated until all elements are processed.

Comment: Thank you very much . Seems like I have quite a lot to learn about ruby . Thank you :)

Comment: @Kalanamith Added step by step explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Functional approach with [Facets](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets):

```
require 'facets'
str.split(":").each_slice(2).map_by { |k, v| [k, v] }.mash { |k, vs| [k, vs.join] }
#=> {"Desc"=>"X1XXSC", "C"=>"CCCC4524", "xxxs"=>"xswd"}
```

Not that you cannot do it without Facets, but it's longer because of some basic abstractions missing in the core:

```
Hash[str.split(":").each_slice(2).group_by(&:first).map { |k, gs| [k, gs.map(&:last).join] }]
#=> {"Desc"=>"X1XXSC", "C"=>"CCCC4524", "xxxs"=>"xswd"}
```

Comment: And we did it again, my `each_with_object` vs. your functional approach :)

Comment: @Sergio: Yeah, I noticed ;-) Now we need another one with `inject`, another one with `each` and we have the usual suspects rounded up again :-) If we had `mash` in the core I think there would be no discussion, but `Hash[...]` is so ugly and anti-OOP I understand nobody wants to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) and [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) here

```
str = "Desc:X1:C:CCCC:Desc:XXSC:xxxs:xswd:C:4524"
hash = str.split(':').each_slice(2).each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), memo|
  memo[key] ||= ''
  memo[key] += value
end

hash # => {"Desc"=>"X1XXSC", "C"=>"CCCC4524", "xxxs"=>"xswd"}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look in to what each_slice and each_with_object do. I'm still learning core ruby

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumerable#slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) is a good way to go.

```
str = "Desc:X1:C:CCCC:Desc:XXSC:xxxs:xswd:C:4524"
a = ["Desc","C","xxxs"] # collect the keys in a separate collection.
str.split(":").slice_before(""){|i| a.include? i}
# => [["Desc", "X1"], ["C", "CCCC"], ["Desc", "XXSC"], ["xxxs", "xswd"], ["C", "4524"]]
hsh = str.split(":").slice_before(""){|i| a.include? i}.each_with_object(Hash.new("")) do |i,h|
  h[i[0]] += i[1]
end
hsh
# => {"Desc"=>"X1XXSC", "C"=>"CCCC4524", "xxxs"=>"xswd"}
```